# Unable to add column after successfully using scaffold to create a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. the above suggested answers did not seem to clarify for me what to do. I am very new to this unfortunately.
2. Problem In reading Rails Crash Course I created a "Post" table using this script

```
rails generate scaffold Post author:string title:string body:text
rake db:migrate
```

3. So as part of my learning I proceeded to adding new columns.
   I scripted the following:-

```
rails generate migration add_comments_to_posts comments:text
rake db:migrate.
```

4. Checked ~db/migrate/updated posts - the updated column is present
   Checked ~db/schema - updated column is also present. ( t.text comments ) noted in the file.
5. When I opened my web browser and tried to display the table all I get was the original 3 columns without the new columns being displayed.

How do I add a column to a 'scaffolded' table?
To all my sincerest thank you for taking the time to help this very elderly student.( I am 75 years old)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the new column to your views? You have to add new columns to your view files. 
app/views/posts/index.html.erb
app/views/posts/show.html.erb

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to respond earlier however I must have not done it right and I believe my reply did not get through. I am certainly going to include checking and updating ‘view’. It all makes sense especially now and remembering the MVC architecture. Thanks again.

Comment: Mr. Sharma thank you for your help. I tried your instructions and was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am happy that my answer helped you. May I please request you to please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The "rails generate scaffold..." command generates a lot of code, including the view. But the "rails generate migration..." only modifies the database schema.

In order to see the new comments field in your browser, you will need to modify the views (the files with the .erb extension) and add it there.

Comment: Thank You PPS I was able to add the column following your and Mr. Vikram Sharma's advises. I wish the book Rails Crash Course had been clearer. In any event I appreciate your help and a comment; I am not sure I can recommend that book to a newbie like me.

Comment: To Mr. Sharma and PPP I would like to add a followup to your help.

Comment: To Mr. Sharma and PPP I would like to add a followup to your help. I was able to display the webpage on localhost:3000/posts the new column title. However when I tried to create a 'new post' the new column called 'comments' did not show in the form displayed and I was not able to add any comments. After searching through the ~/view/posts/_form.html I noted that 'comments' block missing. I inserted this block <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :comments %>
    <%= form.text_area :comments %>
  </div>  and was able to display the form correctly and was able to create/edit my first post.

Comment: I think this may be the last comment regarding this issue. I had to make additions referencing the new column -comments, in 8 different folders before my table worked as I hoped it would.

Comment: Please also note that you have to add any new attributes in the list of accepted parameters in your controller.